# How to get a script from html with jsoup in android

Tags: android, jsoup

I want to get "Hash Brown Casserole for the Slow Cooker Recipe" and "PT20M" from following script tag in a html using jsoup. I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707679/how-to-get-this-script-from-html-with-jsoup-in-android-programming) but I didn't get a clear solution. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
<script id="ld" type="application/ld+json">{"@context": "http://schema.org/","@type": "Recipe","name": "Hash Brown Casserole for the Slow Cooker Recipe","prepTime":"PT20M"</script>
```

Comment: Is there anybody here?!

Answer (score 1):

See there is id in script. you can take element by id and there is one child. then you can convert this child to json object.Here is example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<script id=\"ld\" type=\"application/ld+json\">{\"@context\": \"http://schema.org/\",\"@type\": \"Recipe\",\"name\": \"Hash Brown Casserole for the Slow Cooker Recipe\",\"prepTime\":\"PT20M\"}</script>");
        String str = doc.getElementById("ld").childNodes().get(0).toString();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
        System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("name"));
        System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("prepTime"));
```

**your script contains: 
`{"@context": "http://schema.org/","@type": "Recipe","name": "Hash Brown Casserole for the Slow Cooker Recipe","prepTime":"PT20M"`

if there is no `}` after `PT20M` then you need to concat `}` .

```
String str = doc.getElementById("ld").childNodes().get(0).toString()+"}";
```